# ReactJs with MUI 5 Autocomplete using http request, filtered options not displayed for specific search

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've implemented search option by using Autocomplete component and options doesn't display for specific phrase "apple airp", but for phrase "apple airpo", options are displayed

[image]
[image]

This how my component looks like:

```
export function SearchProduct() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  
  async function getData(searchTerm) {


    const productResponse = await ProductApi.searchProduct(searchTerm);
    if (productResponse.length !== 0) {
      setOptions(productResponse);
    }
 
  }

  const onInputChange = (event, value, reason) => {
    if (value && value.length > 2) {
      //   value = value.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "");

      getData(value);
    } else {
      setOptions([]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
        <SearchIcon sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
        <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: 600 }}>
          <Autocomplete
            freeSolo
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={options}
            onInputChange={onInputChange}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} label="Търси" variant="standard" />
            )}
          />
        </Stack>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

And searchRequest method:

```
static async searchProduct(searchTerm) {

    const response = await axios.get(
      `${BASE_URL}/products/search/?s=${searchTerm}`
    );

    return response.data;
  }
```

In both cases, I receive BE responses with correct data, so I am excluding problem relation with BE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add extra property in my Autocomplete component  to render new results from BE `filterOptions={(options) => options}`

From documentation:
[image]